# Powershell creating pscustomobject object

Tags: json, powershell, pscustomobject

I need help on something I really can't figure out. I have a file containing loads of these ID's

[image]

I need to create a json payload in powershell to look like this containing each of these ID's

```
{
  "assetIds": [
    "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "f86354c4-8e69-4cee-b85c-11b9534019e0",
    "6829c1ad-17d8-4d9c-93c7-2a4b6acfc201"
  ],
  "sendNotification": true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly straightforward:

```
# define object
$object = [pscustomobject]@{
  assetIds = @(
    Get-Content path\to\file.txt
  ) -as [string[]]
  sendNotification = $true
}

# convert to JSON
$object |ConvertTo-Json
```

The `@()` (the "subexpression operator") ensures the value of the `assetIds` property will always be an array (even if `Get-Content` returns 0 or only 1 ID)

The `-as [string[]]` conversion prevents PowerShell from serializing extended properties that might have been attached to the strings by `Get-Content`

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for. Question though, How do you i remove the rest of the fields. I'm only interested to see what's in the value field "assetIds": [
    {
      "value": "4a507ef9-185b-461a-ad8d-7f3dbd91da0c",
      "PSPath": "C:\\temp\\assets.txt",
      "PSParentPath": "C:\\temp",
      "PSChildName": "assets.txt",
      "PSDrive": "C",
      "PSProvider": "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem",
      "ReadCount": 1
    },

Comment: Found it, thank you :)

Comment: @Hein Couple of ways to go about it, but the easiest is to just convert the resulting array to `[string[]]` (I've updated the answer)

Comment: wow you're amazing!!! thank you so so much